# Why a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a surface while from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a curve?

Tags: calculus

This is a silly question, but I just can not see the reason.

Comment: What happened when you worked out examples from, let's say, a multivariable calculus textbook? Could you plot the curves and surfaces in question? Did you learn to visualize them?

Comment: Wikipedia said "*In mathematics, a surface is a generalization of a plane which doesn't need to be flat – that is, the curvature is not necessarily zero. **This is analogous to a curve generalizing a straight line***. "

Comment: With certain regularity  assumptions $f$ will be a local diffeomorphism.   Surfaces resemble $\Bbb R^2$ locally.  Curves $\Bbb R^1$.

Comment: Do you mean "$\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$"?

Comment: $(x,y,f(x,y))$ could describe a surface,  if I understand the OP.  @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: The _graph_ of the first function is a surface.

Answer (score -1):

The function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^2$ has to be a curve (a unidimensional object) because you are encoding information about a single variable. So, even a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^3$ will also be a curve in 3-D.

However, the function $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ encodes information from two variables into one. Hence it is represented as a surface (a 2-dimensional object).